# Java: Find position of elements in an array from another array

Tags: java, algorithm, indexing, position

I have two arrays:

a = [a1,a2,a3,a4,..,an] ordered in ascending;

b = [b1,b2,b3,..., bm] ordered in ascending;

I want to know the position of the elements of array b in array a.

Is there a fast way to do it instead of finding one by one?

Comment: If the arrays are sorted yes.

Comment: for each b:x you can binarySearch from the subarray of a:k to a:n, where k is indexOf b:x-1 in a

Comment: Any idea about the algorithm?

Comment: He said, binary search. That IS the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned arrays are sorted, you can perform binary search.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 5, 7 };
        int b[] = { -2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int position = Arrays.binarySearch(a, b[i]);
            if (position >= 0)
                System.out.println("Element " + b[i] + " is at " + position
                        + " in array A");
            else {
                // System.out.println("Element does not exist in array A");
                int lower = -1;
                int upper = -1;
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (b[i] > a[j]) {
                        lower = j;
                    } else {
                        upper = j;
                    }
                    if (upper != -1)
                        break;
                }
                if (upper <= 0)
                    System.out.println("Element " + b[i] + " is at before 0");
                else
                    System.out.println("Element " + b[i] + " is Between "
                            + lower + " and " + upper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have used in-built library for binary search. Hope it helps!
I have updated the code.

Comment: I also need the position of element b even the element does not exits in array A, so the binary search is not working here.

Comment: How can you even get the position of element of b when it does not exist in array A. Just print -1 in else instead of "Element does not exist". Or try printing `position` in else (if that's what you want)

Comment: sorry, "position" here I mean if the element dose not exit in array A, it will give the low and up boundary of the element. Let's use the array in your example, the element "3" in Array b does not exit in array A, but I also need the boundary of "3" in array A, that is between a[1] and a[2] (a[1]=2, a[2]=5).

Comment: Thank you, this is more or less the same algorithm I used now.

Answer (score 0):

O(m)+O(n)

```
    //assuming both a and b are sorted in ascending order
    int startA = 0, startB = 0;
    int[] a = {2,4,6,8,9};
    int[] b = {1,4,9};
    int[] result = new int[b.length];
    //result[i] suggest position of ith element of array b in array a. you can initialize all elements of result to -1 indicating not present in a
    int endB = b.length, endA = a.length;
    while(startB<endB && startA<endA){
        if(b[startB]<a[startA]){
            startB++;
        }
        else if(b[startB]>a[startA]){
            startA++;
        }
        else{
            result[startB]=startA;
            startB++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is not working if there is a element in array b bigger than any element of array a.

Comment: Since both arrays are sorted in ascending order if any element in B let's say X  is greater than last element in A that means all the elements in B after X will not be present in array A. so result array will contain -1 for all these elements.